# No wlan0 interface after apt upgrade in PI 400

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I have run `apt` to install updates yesterday. I saw new kernel was there too and I let it do. There was no error. Once I started PI today there were some errors:

- kernel modules were not loaded because module aliases lp, pppdev, parport_pc and i2c_dev were not implemented
- no wireless interface detected

It is the latest PI OS Bulls eye 11, october 2021.

I have commented out those modules to overcome the first trouble. But the wireless network makes me crazy.

`/etc/network/interface` is default

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

which is an empty directory.

`ifconfig` does not list `wlan0`

`iwlist wlan0 scan` show the interface does not support scanning

Is something wrong with my configuration or did just hw died? I am using an official Pi charger. How can I fix wifi?

Update

I have installed fresh version on USB stick and booted it. I can connect to my wifi, so hardware is fine. I cannot find a difference in configuration. The original SD card uses 11.2 debian version while new USB has 11.1.  SD card had kernel 5.10.63-v7l.

I have located the upgraded packages from yesterday. What to do now?
[image]

Comment: Some configurations will not name wifi adapters `wlan[n]` but rather use **persistent** device names like `wlp[n]s[n]`

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try. Nonetheless it should work without stating the interface name, should not it? dhcpcd needs just a wifi connection information, right?